# Single Narrow Sunbeam

Tags: optics

I saw a single narrow sunbeam this cloudy, post-rain, morning as I was driving.  The narrow beam, which seemed only a couple of inches wide, came directly from the sun, arched slightly and ended on the hood of my car.  This beam turned with me as I entered a curve, then was gone.  I've seen this a time or two before.
What causes this unique sight?

Comment: Aliens? I have seen sunbeams coming through holes in clouds, usually caused by light hitting moisture or other particulates and contrasting against the darkness of the cloud shadow, but I've never heard of one only a few inches across, let alone following you as you turn. I will watch this question with interest.

Comment: Could be be a reflection from the curved bonnet (hood) of your car that you are seeing projected onto the windscreen (windshield) to make it look like a sunbeam that curves? Light doesn't curve in the atmosphere (no smart arse graded refractive index comments please).

Comment: The curvature is almost certainly an optical illusion caused by the eye's inability to judge distance for something "hanging" in the atmosphere -- in this case light scattered along the beam path.  A similar effect has led panic-newscasters to wonder if a rocket launch or jet trail is curving all over when in fact it's just a "compressed" view of the change in distance to the viewed object.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I do think it must have had something to do with the moisture from the recent rain.  If it ever happens again I will definitely try to get a picture.

Comment: Should have stuck my head out the window to eliminate possibility that the windshield was having some effect (might explain the curvature).  I was so intent on the beam that I almost ran a red light at the curve in the road.  Thanks again for the input.

Answer (score -1):

'Arched Slightly' is a key comment here. Light does not bend unless going from one medium to another. Therefore, if the narrow beam of light seemed to bend in its path, it had to have been a phenomena of reflection or refraction. It could be that you were sampling only part of a larger beam that was somehow getting to your eye via an unknown mechanism (I like the English bloke who used the word 'Bonnet'. That might have something to do with it). Either that or it was LGM's probing you. 'Little Green Men'